# How do I execute my glob command in my .virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure how to execute my glob script that I wrote through vim.

```
import glob

glob.glob('igm/projects/Water_Contamination/input', '*.gz')
glob.glob('igm/projects/Water_Contamination/output/matching_output', '*.gz')
glob.glob('igm/projetcs/Water_Contamination/output/nonmatching_output', '*.gz')
glob.glob('igm/projects/Water_Contamination/references', '*txt', '*gz', '*fatsa')
glob.glob('igm/projects/Water_Contamination/stats', '*.txt')


def build_command(args):    
    input = glob(args.input)
    matching_output = glob(args.matching_output)
    nonmatching_output = glob(args.nonmatching_output)
    stats = glob(args.stats)
    reference = glob(args.reference)
```

Comment: Have you tried activating your virtualenv and running `python /path/to/globby/script.py`?

Comment: Thank you! That was just what I needed!